# Range Slider with 1 handle and 2 value input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

hello mates is it possible Range Slider 1 handle and 2 value input. please visit this link  `[1]: https://codepen.io/beepye/pen/RgYMPP`

Comment: your question is not clear. thanks

Comment: @XenioGracias can you plesae revisit this link ?

Comment: yes.. i can visit it